# C# Parsing Issue

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a database , and I use ADO.net to get data from it , so I used a SQL Data adapter to fill my data in Datatable DT.
I have an Attribute float x ,
I want to parse a column in my DT to float here's the code :

```
 foreach (DataRow row in DT.Rows)
        {

                x = float.Parse(row[6].ToString()F),

        }
```

it highlights the F in red and tells me The Name F does not exist in the current context syntax error , ',' expected .

thanks

Comment: So you are trying to convert a string to a float? Well what is that F even for if you are parsing it anyways?

Comment: Did you try removing `F`? Do you expect it to make things `float`, as in `123.45F`?

Comment: no actually it is stored in the database as decimal but row is a DataRow object , I can't just type x = row[6] ; it tells me can't convert type object to float , so I had to get the string representation by using ToString()

Comment: I want in the end for x to read something like 8.9 , if I can exclude the F , I got no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it tells me can't convert type `object` to `float`

Use [`Convert.ToSingle()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12wk8d8z(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead:

```
foreach (DataRow row in DT.Rows) {
    x = Convert.ToSingle(row[6]);
}
```